# Game wont go back to previous screen in Corona?

Tags: storyboard, coronasdk

My game goes like this Menu->Game->Back to Menu. But it wong go back to the menu. I know the code `storyboard.gotoScene( "menu", "crossFade", 1000 )` is correct because i used it in another scene but it wont seem to work on my game?

Here is my back to menu button:

```
local menuBut = ui.newButton{
    default = "menuBut.png",
    over = "menuBut.png",
    onRelease = function(event) group:removeSelf(); storyboard.gotoScene( "menu", "crossFade", 1000 ) ; end
}
group:insert(menuBut)


menuBut.x = 650
menuBut.y = 458
```

Also, the function where my Back to Menu button is located above the createScene function. Could that be the problem? I cant put it below the createScene function because the button will appear if some conditions are true.

Comment: You don't need to remove `group` as the storyboard will do it if you have everything setup properly. Your problem is too broad. Duplicate it with a small complete example.

Answer (score 0):

What happens then? Nothing?

I think that you are removing the button before the scene transition takes place, since the button is in 'group' . I believe your code will nil the button prematurely.

Skip the group:removeSelf() here and move that part to destroyScene instead.

Comment: Yes nothing happens. Ive also tried removing the group:removeSelf() and then asking it to go to a function that will direct it to the previous screen but it still wont work?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console log?  Personally I don't like using anonymous functions (closures) like that for event handlers.